# Spring SAML WSO2 Refresh Assertion

Tags: spring, wso2, saml, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

I have configured Spring SAML application with WSO2. When user is logging in, he retrieve assertion with validity equals 5 minutes. But after 5 minutes are gone, there is no refresh assertion occured.

How to enable calling `/saml/sso` on page reload after assertion is expired? Maybe do you know another solution? Some bean's properies?

`maxAuthenticationAge` in `org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl` do not working.

`forceAuthN` in `org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions` do not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in assertion was not `SessionNotOnOrAfter` property in `AuthnStatement`, so expiration time was `null`. In this case, I am getting expiration time from `Conditions` element from `NotOnOrAfter` property, IMHO it has same value as `SessionNotOnOrAfter` should have.

Secondly, to be safety I minus 1 minute from expiration time to be sure, that assertion will always be alive.

Workaround is to override in custom `SAMLAuthenticationProvider` `getExpirationDate` method:

```
protected Date getExpirationDate(SAMLCredential credential) {
    List<AuthnStatement> statementList = credential.getAuthenticationAssertion().getAuthnStatements();
    DateTime expiration = null;
    for (AuthnStatement statement : statementList) {
        DateTime newExpiration = statement.getSessionNotOnOrAfter();
        if (newExpiration != null) {
            if (expiration == null || expiration.isAfter(newExpiration)) {
                expiration = newExpiration;
            }
        }
    }
    if (expiration == null) {
        Conditions conditions = credential.getAuthenticationAssertion().getConditions();
        expiration = conditions.getNotOnOrAfter();
    }
    return expiration != null ? expiration.minusMinutes(1).toDate() : null;
}
```